# Two coin tossed simultaneously

Tags: probability

If two coins are tossed simultaneously 4 times, What will be the probability of getting exactly two heads? 
Suppose that one knows that there is at least one toss that yields two heads, compute the probability that there is exactly one toss that yields two heads?

The sample space is too large to do counting. Any shorter way to solve this?

Comment: The sample space isn't that big. Just write it all out on paper.

Comment: 4 power 4 is 256.So if asked in an exam, it will be tedious to calculate no?

Comment: Rather than writing down the sample space (a very odd suggestion indeed), use the definition of independence. But first, what do you mean by "getting exactly two heads"? Is it getting 2 heads from 8 throws? Then the $8$ throws are independent hence, if the coins are fair, the answer is ${8\choose2}2^{-8}$.

Comment: I apologize for my earlier comment, it was not well thought out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two (presumably fair) coins being thrown four times each is equivalent to one coin being thrown eight times - order is irrelevant as each event is independent. We can model this with a binomial distribution: the number of heads, $X$, is given by $X \sim B(8, 0.5)$.

$P(X=2) = \binom{8}{2}0.5^2(1-0.5)^6 = 28\times\frac{1}{256} = 0.109375$ (or $\frac{7}{64}$).

If you're not familiar with the binomial distribution, the $\binom{8}{2}$ is the number of ways that two heads out of 8 could be tossed (i.e. 1st and 2nd; 1st and 3rd; 1st and 4th; ...; 7th and 8th). Then $0.5$ is the probability of a head - this event must occur twice, so we square it, and $1-0.5$ is the probability of a tail - this occurs six times, so we raise it to that power.

For the next question, let's say $Y$ is the number of times we roll two heads with our two dice. I believe you're asking for $P(Y=1\;|\;Y\ge1)$. We can again model $Y$ with a binomial distribution, noting that the probability that both coins are heads is a quarter: $Y\sim B(4, 0.25)$.

Now, $P(Y=1) = \binom{4}{1}0.25^1(1-0.25)^3 = \frac{27}{64}$.

$P(Y\ge1) = 1 - P(Y = 0) = 1 - (1-0.25)^4 = 1-\frac{81}{256} = \frac{175}{256}$.

So the probability that the former is true, given that the latter is, is: $\frac{27}{64} \div \frac{175}{256} = \frac{27\times256}{64\times175} = \frac{108}{175}\approx0.6171$.

Comment: In the second part of the answer, if you take the events of tossing the coins to be independent,  won't that make it P(a/b)=P(a)? The following steps are necessary?

Comment: $P(A | B) = P(A)$ is true if B is independent of A. In the case of $P(Y=1\;|\;Y\ge1)$, the coin tosses are independent but the actual events on each side of the "|" are not, because they are both giving statements about the value of Y.